# Tentei fazer um algoritmo que gere uma matriz aleatoria e exiba o menor elemento mais a sua posição

Tags: python, array, algoritmo, variáveis, matriz

Esse é o enunciado do exercico:
*Desenvolver um algoritmo que gere uma matriz (7,4) contendo valores inteiros aleatórios. Após, encontrar o menor valor contido na matriz e sua posição.*

Isso é o que consegui esboçar por enquanto:

```py
from numpy import *

M1=random.randint(100, size=(28))

a=array(M1).reshape(7,4)

print("\nM1\n",a)

menor_valor=a.min()

pos=M1.index(a)

print("\nO menor valor da matriz é: ",menor_valor)
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida ?

Comment: Como faço para que o algoritmo exiba a posição do menor elemento?

Answer (score 0):

Sem numpy eu consegui dessa forma:

Inicia a variável minimum em 0, procura o menor elemento de cada linha da matriz e os compara. Se o menor elemento da linha atual for menor que o menor elemento da linha anterior, o valor na variável minimum será substituído.

```
minimum, aux, position = 0, 0, (0,0)

for i in range (nRows):
    aux = minimum
    for j in range (nCol):
        # Procura o valor mínimo no vetor i que compõem a matriz 
        minimum = (min(matriz[i]))
        # Operações de comparação 
        if aux < minimum:
            minimum = aux 
        elif aux > minimum: 
            aux = minimum
            #Armazena a posição do menor elemento até o momento
            position = (i, matriz[i].index(minimum))
        else:
            continue

print(minimum)
print(position)
```

Answer (score -2):

Não testei, mas pesquise sobre *numpy.where()*

Da uma olhada no final desse site: https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/python/python-find-index-of-value-in-array/

Deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deu certinho, amigo! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Cliquei na seta pra cima, pra dizer que a resposta foi util, mas contabilizou como -1. Desculpe, sou novato aqui e estou aprendendo a usa este ambiente

Comment: Tranquilo. É que como eu fiz uma resposta sem muita explicação o site está dizendo para eu adicionar mais informações, acho que por isso ele deu negativo. Também sou novato.